# How to display in widget the complex JSON using flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My problem is i don't know how to display the Object inside the Object of JSON.
But i already display the Outer Object like name, usermae etc. And i want to display the object inside the Address and Geo. Im new to JSON and flutter please guide me

i read this but i dont know what i need [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51)

the code is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wc8ecFSu5N8&t=152s)

JSON OUTPUT json is from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
},
]
```

MODEL
i generate my model in [here](https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<UserModel> userModelFromJson(String str) => 
List<UserModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => UserModel.fromJson(x)));

String userModelToJson(List<UserModel> data) => 
json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class UserModel {
int id;
String name;
String username;
String email;
Address address;
String phone;
String website;
Company company;

UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.address,
    this.phone,
    this.website,
    this.company,
});

factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    username: json["username"],
    email: json["email"],
    address: Address.fromJson(json["address"]),
    phone: json["phone"],
    website: json["website"],
    company: Company.fromJson(json["company"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "username": username,
    "email": email,
    "address": address.toJson(),
    "phone": phone,
    "website": website,
    "company": company.toJson(),
};
}

class Address {
String street;
String suite;
String city;
String zipcode;
Geo geo;

Address({
    this.street,
    this.suite,
    this.city,
    this.zipcode,
    this.geo,
});

factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Address(
    street: json["street"],
    suite: json["suite"],
    city: json["city"],
    zipcode: json["zipcode"],
    geo: Geo.fromJson(json["geo"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "street": street,
    "suite": suite,
    "city": city,
    "zipcode": zipcode,
    "geo": geo.toJson(),
};
}

class Geo {
String lat;
String lng;

Geo({
    this.lat,
    this.lng,
});

factory Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Geo(
    lat: json["lat"],
    lng: json["lng"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "lat": lat,
    "lng": lng,
};
}

class Company {
String name;
String catchPhrase;
String bs;

Company({
    this.name,
    this.catchPhrase,
    this.bs,
});

factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Company(
    name: json["name"],
    catchPhrase: json["catchPhrase"],
    bs: json["bs"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "catchPhrase": catchPhrase,
    "bs": bs,
};
}
```

Services.dart

```
  class Services {
static const String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
static Future<List<UserModel>> getUsers() async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (200 == response.statusCode) {
      final List<UserModel> users = userModelFromJson(response.body);
      return users;
    } else {
      return List<UserModel>();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return List<UserModel>();
  }
}
```

}

HomeView.dart

```
class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

List<UserModel> _users;
bool _loading;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

_loading = true;
Services.getUsers().then((users) {
  setState(() {
    _users = users;
    _loading = false;
  });
});
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(

  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Users'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _users == null ? 0 : _users.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        UserModel user = _users[index];
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(user.name),
              subtitle: Text(user.email),
              trailing: Text(user.phone),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  );
}
}
```

Thank you for your kindness

Comment: So is your code not working because it looks like you got it right to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model that you create is correct, you have (Good habit) only to check the objects inside your model before you parse them

```
UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   // ...
    address =
        json['address'] != null ? new Address.fromJson(json['address']) : null;
    company =
        json['company'] != null ? new Company.fromJson(json['company']) : null;
   // ...
  }
```

On your service class use the fetch way that is set on flutter documentation to simplify your code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<UserModel>> fetchUsers(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

  return parseUsers(response.body);
}

List<UserModel> parseUsers(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<UserModel>((json) => UserModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

and once you get the data from json you can access to every object based on the hierarchy inside the json, in your case the stateful widget would look like, where i replace the name and the phone with latitude inside the geo and city inside the address

```
class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  List<UserModel> _users;
  bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _loading = true;
    fetchUsers(http.Client()).then((users) {
      setState(() {
        _users = users;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Users'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _users == null ? 0 : _users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            UserModel user = _users[index];
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(user.name),
                  subtitle: Text(user.address.geo.lat),
                  trailing: Text(user.address.city),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this help

Comment: My pleasure @KenVerganio!

Comment: Hello @Mohamed Dernoun i have one more question how about  address object replace with this

"friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Bell Gilmore"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Brady Armstrong"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Lambert Lott"
      }
    ],

can you help me how to display this object thank you

Comment: an array inside the object please help me thank you

Comment: is your question how to fetch data inside an array that is inside an Object ?

Comment: you can fetch data over a list with this method that use for loop to get the detail of an object inside an array 

Friend getFriend(int friendID) {
      // friends is your list of object
      for (int i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        if (friends.elementAt(i).id == friendID) {
          return friends.elementAt(i);
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
print(getFriend(id).name);

Comment: it's not well formatted in comment, check my answer in this link    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129266/flutter-how-to-show-single-value-from-list/61134422#61134422

Comment: help me @Mohamed Dernoun for this last request that i dm
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211337/discussion-between-ken-verganio-and-mohamed-dernoun).

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can directly assign attribute 
code snippet

```
title: Text('${user.name} ${user.address.city} ${user.address.geo.lat}'),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

List<UserModel> userModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<UserModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => UserModel.fromJson(x)));

String userModelToJson(List<UserModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class UserModel {
  int id;
  String name;
  String username;
  String email;
  Address address;
  String phone;
  String website;
  Company company;

  UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.address,
    this.phone,
    this.website,
    this.company,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        username: json["username"],
        email: json["email"],
        address: Address.fromJson(json["address"]),
        phone: json["phone"],
        website: json["website"],
        company: Company.fromJson(json["company"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "username": username,
        "email": email,
        "address": address.toJson(),
        "phone": phone,
        "website": website,
        "company": company.toJson(),
      };
}

class Address {
  String street;
  String suite;
  String city;
  String zipcode;
  Geo geo;

  Address({
    this.street,
    this.suite,
    this.city,
    this.zipcode,
    this.geo,
  });

  factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Address(
        street: json["street"],
        suite: json["suite"],
        city: json["city"],
        zipcode: json["zipcode"],
        geo: Geo.fromJson(json["geo"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "street": street,
        "suite": suite,
        "city": city,
        "zipcode": zipcode,
        "geo": geo.toJson(),
      };
}

class Geo {
  String lat;
  String lng;

  Geo({
    this.lat,
    this.lng,
  });

  factory Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Geo(
        lat: json["lat"],
        lng: json["lng"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lat": lat,
        "lng": lng,
      };
}

class Company {
  String name;
  String catchPhrase;
  String bs;

  Company({
    this.name,
    this.catchPhrase,
    this.bs,
  });

  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Company(
        name: json["name"],
        catchPhrase: json["catchPhrase"],
        bs: json["bs"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "catchPhrase": catchPhrase,
        "bs": bs,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeView(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class Services {
  static const String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  static Future<List<UserModel>> getUsers() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        final List<UserModel> users = userModelFromJson(response.body);
        return users;
      } else {
        return List<UserModel>();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return List<UserModel>();
    }
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  List<UserModel> _users;
  bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _loading = true;
    Services.getUsers().then((users) {
      setState(() {
        _users = users;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Users'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _users == null ? 0 : _users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            UserModel user = _users[index];
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('${user.name} ${user.address.city} ${user.address.geo.lat}'),
                  subtitle: Text(user.email),
                  trailing: Text(user.phone),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thak you for your help